# negative function in python

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization

I have a function defined that calculates the minimum of a function like x^2. I want to define a function that would calculate the maximum of a function by calculating the minimum of a similar function by multiplying through by negative one.

```
def myf(g):
        return -(g+1.3)**2+5
def maximize(f,low,high,tol):
        return minimize(-1*f,low,high,tol)
```

Is there a way to do this? When I try what I have I get the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'function'
```

minimize is defined as such:

```
def minimize(f,low,high, tol):
    if low>high:
        c=low; a=high
        a=float(a); c=float(c);
    else:
        a=float(low); c=float(high);
    b=a+(c-a)*.618033
    fa=f(a); fc=f(c)
    fb=f(b);
    if fb>fa or fb>fc: return maximize(f,low,high,tol)
    while abs(a-c)>tol:
        d=a+(c-b);
        fd=f(d);
        if d<b:
            if fb<fd:
                a=d; fa=fd;
            else:
                c=b; b=d
                fc=fb; fb=fd
        else:           
            if fd<fb:
                a=b; fa=fb; 
                b=d; fb=fd
            else:
                c=d; fc=fd
    return (a+c)/2.
```

Looking for a python code only solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can't multiply a function with a number. Instead, construct a new function that uses the old one and multiplies the *result* (and not the function itself) with a number:

```
def maximize(f,low,high,tol):
    return minimize(lambda x: -f(x),low,high,tol)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this. The most straightforward is to "wrap" your function into another function. You can use lambda: `new_f = lambda x: -f(x)`. In case you are not familiar with lambda's, this is a shortcut for

```
def new_f(x):
    return -f(x)
```

Comment: Thanks, I like the explanation of lambda's.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should be using `scipy.optimize`?

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html

Comment: I would use that however it is in a coding class and we have to build it on our own using methods described in class.